# Fractional Laplacian of smooth cut off functions

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, laplacian, fractional-calculus

Suppose we have a smooth compactly supported function $\phi\in C^{\infty}_c(B_\epsilon(0))$ such that $0\leq \phi \leq 1$, $\phi\equiv 1$ on the unit ball and $\phi$ vanishes outside $B_\epsilon(0).$

Suppose we have that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\nabla \phi|^p=\int_{1<|x|<\epsilon} |\nabla \phi|^p dx \to 0$$
as $\epsilon \to \infty.$

Then can we get similar results if we replace $\nabla$ by its nonlocal counterpart $(-\Delta)^{s/2}$ for $s\in (0,2)?$ So in other words do we have that,

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |(-\Delta)^{s/2} \phi|^p \to 0$$
as $\epsilon \to \infty.$

Comment: @WillieWong thank you for your remarks. I changed the notation to be more clear and corrected the question based on your comments.

Comment: Can you still be more precise? As stated for an arbitrary family of $C^\infty_c$ functions $\phi_\epsilon$ with the conditions you stated, it is still not the case that $\lim_{\epsilon\to\infty} \int |\nabla \phi_\epsilon|^p = 0$. You need additional assumptions on how the $\epsilon$ is incorporated. Please give at least an indication on how you are treating the $\epsilon$-dependence.

Comment: For example, one case where it does work partially is $\phi_\epsilon = \phi_1( x/ \epsilon)$; this will satisfy your stated conditions. But this has $\| \nabla\phi_\epsilon\|_{L^p} = \epsilon^{d/p-1} \|\nabla\phi_1\|_{L^p}$, so in this case you only get the limit to zero if $d < p$ (here $d$ is the spatial dimension. But it will fail when $d \geq p$.

Comment: More generally, thinking about just the case $p = 2$, you can take the Fourier transform and your question is essentially: if I have a family of functions $\phi_\epsilon$ such that $\int |\xi|^2 |\phi_\epsilon|^2 \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, what can I say about $\int |\xi|^{2s} |\phi_\epsilon|^2 $ for $s \neq 2$? The answer is "not very much". You may get better answers is you specify how the $\phi_\epsilon$ are related to each other.